# Sequelize scoped BelongsTo / HasMany not being able to include

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

For my project I recently had to split up a model into 2 different models. but a main model always referenced one or the other, so I did the following:

```js
// model1.model.ts
export class Model1 extends Model {
 @BelongsTo(() => Model2, {
    foreignKey: 'linkId',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      linkType: 'model2'
    }
  })
  models2: Model2;

 @BelongsTo(() => Model3, {
    foreignKey: 'linkId',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      linkType: 'model3'
    }
  })
  models3: Model3;

  @Column
  linkId: string;

  @Column
  linkType: string;
}

// model2.model.ts
export class Model2 extends Model {
  @HasMany(() => Model1, {
    foreignKey: 'linkId',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      linkType: 'model2'
    }
  })
  models1: Model1 [];
}

// model3.model.ts
export class Model3 extends Model {
  @HasMany(() => Model1, {
    foreignKey: 'linkId',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      linkType: 'model3'
    }
  })
  models1: Model1 [];
}
```

This seemed to work great for my graphql side connecting to the data, but now I'm trying to access the data from a other part in my backend code. this however gives me the following error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: column model2.linkType does not exist
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```js
const testing = await Model1.findAll({
      where,
      attributes: [
        // some attributes
      ],
      include: [
         {model: Model2},
         {model: Model3},
      ],
});
```

I tried some include configurations, but all of them throw a error that looks like I'm going at it wrong. Does anybody have any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?

grts Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why this was giving me issues, `Model1` didn't need to reference the scope

```js
// model1.model.ts
export class Model1 extends Model {
 @BelongsTo(() => Model2, {
    foreignKey: 'linkId',
    constraints: false,
  })
  models2: Model2;

 @BelongsTo(() => Model3, {
    foreignKey: 'linkId',
    constraints: false,
  })
  models3: Model3;

  @Column
  linkId: string;

  @Column
  linkType: string;
}
```

And everything was solved :)